# Scaling and animating Google Maps heatmap and immediate changes with slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, visualization, heatmap

Please see the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaysunice3401/KawjQ/) -- you may also want to see this [example](https://www.google.com/publicdata/explore?ds=d5bncppjof8f9_&ctype=b&strail=false&nselm=s&met_x=sp_dyn_le00_in&scale_x=lin&ind_x=false&met_y=sp_dyn_tfrt_in&scale_y=lin&ind_y=false&met_s=sp_pop_totl&scale_s=lin&ind_s=false&dimp_c=country%3aregion&ifdim=country&iconSize=0.5&uniSize=0.035#!ctype=m&strail=false&bcs=d&nselm=s&met_s=sp_pop_totl&scale_s=lin&ind_s=false&dimp_c=country%3aregion&ifdim=country&pit=605250000000&hl=en_US&dl=en_US&ind=false) for clues as to the functionality I'm trying to obtain.

I would like to create a dynamic / animated heatmap and I am open to suggestions.  That is, a heatmap that can change its data set according to a slider (eventually, I may want to add a "play" button to animate this).  I have started the process using Google Maps V3 JavaScript API.  I have several questions/concerns:

1. I am doubtful of loading all of the data into separate arrays like in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaysunice3401/KawjQ/) -- with probably around 20 data sets at 300,000+ points each, I don't think this will scale?  Should this go into JSON and some type of AJAX pull?

   ```
   pointArray  = new google.maps.MVCArray(taxiData);
   pointArray2 = new google.maps.MVCArray(taxiData2);
   pointArray3 = new google.maps.MVCArray(taxiData3);

   var inputYear = $('#input-year');

   inputYear.change(function() {
     var year = $(this).val() * 1;
     if (year == 1) {
       heatmap.setData(pointArray);
     } else if (year == 2) {
       heatmap.setData(pointArray2);
     } else {
       heatmap.setData(pointArray3);
     }
   })
   ```
2. Why doesn't my change event fire immediately on the slider that changes the radius?  That is, the radius of the heatmap does not change until I release my mouse click?

   ```
   var radiusSlider = $('#radius-slider');

   radiusSlider.change(function() {
     heatmap.set('radius', radiusSlider.val()*1);
   })
   ```
3. Maybe this isn't a good approach?  I've seen nice examples on [Google's Public Data Explorer](https://www.google.com/publicdata/explore?ds=d5bncppjof8f9_&ctype=b&strail=false&nselm=s&met_x=sp_dyn_le00_in&scale_x=lin&ind_x=false&met_y=sp_dyn_tfrt_in&scale_y=lin&ind_y=false&met_s=sp_pop_totl&scale_s=lin&ind_s=false&dimp_c=country%3aregion&ifdim=country&iconSize=0.5&uniSize=0.035#!ctype=m&strail=false&bcs=d&nselm=s&met_s=sp_pop_totl&scale_s=lin&ind_s=false&dimp_c=country%3aregion&ifdim=country&pit=605250000000&hl=en_US&dl=en_US&ind=false) but I'm not sure if these can be extended with heatmapping functionality nor are any source/code examples given.  Should/can this be a Motion Chart?  Other approaches (i.e., AngularJS)?

Many thanks for any help or guidance.

Comment: Some other ideas I've thought about are rendering the heatmap output as static image or geojson, but I'm not sure if that's possible?  Plus, I would lose a lot of interactivity as one would no longer be able to zoom and/or change the radius?